# Breaking out and/or removing a paragraph in a contenteditable block

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have recently been playing with contenteditable quite a lot. I've knocked up a simple editor prototype which I'm fairly happy with. There is one thing that's puzzling me.

If I have a paragraph and my cursor (caret) is inside it like so:

```
<p>some text |</p>
```

How do I break out of the paragraph? Is there a key combination or a execCommand that can be used to break out of it on the next line?

If I place the cursor (caret) at the end of the paragraph and press enter a new empty `p` tag is generated. This is fine normally when writing text blocks. But say I want to insert an image or codeblock. I don't want this to be inside a `p` tag but I can't see a way to break out.

I've tried highlighting the whole p block and then use:

```
document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);
```

Which works for other inline formatting (e.g. bold) but doesn't do anything in this case.

[Here is a JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NMmxu/6/), that might make more sense.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "caret", are you referring to the "pipe" character?

Comment: No. I'm talking about the blinking cursor in the content editable. It is often referred to as the caret. The pipe is often used when describing selection scenarios. Have edited to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @madcapnmckay have you been able to resolve this issue?